# fetch_assoc returns last inserted elements

Tags: php, mysql

For some reasons mysql returns only last inserted element in table,could anyone give a tip what's wrong with my code? i'm just practicing php and trying to figure out best ways to make functions easily reusable(just practicing oop i mean). i know this is a bad way but it's only for practice purposes.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php 
        class Database{
            public $db;

            public function __construct($host,$username,$password,$dbname){

                $this->db=new MySQLi($host,$username,$password,$dbname);

            }
            public function getData(){
                $query="SELECT * FROM artisan";
                $result=$this->db->query($query);
                if($result->num_rows>0){
                    while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
                        echo "ID: ".$row["id"]. "-Username: ".$row["username"]. ", "."Email: ".$row["email"]."<br>";
                    }
                }else{
                    echo "No results found!";
                }

            }
            public function getContent(){
                $query="SELECT * FROM content";
                $result=$this->db->query($query);
                $values=array();
                if($result->num_rows>0){
                    while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
                    $values=array(
                        "title"=>$row['title'],
                        "body"=>$row['body']
                    );
                }

            }
            return $values;
            }
        }
        $database=new Database('localhost','root','','test');
        $database->getData();
        $values=$database->getContent();

     ?>

     <style type="text/css">
        .container{
            text-align:center;
        }
     </style>
     <div class="container">
      <?php

        for($i=0;$i<count($values);$i++){
        echo $values["title"]."<br>";
        echo $values["body"]."<br>";
      }
       ?>
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Instead of `$values=array(...` you want `$values[]=array(...`: You are overwriting your array in the loop.

Comment: Side note: embedded styles outside of `<head><head>` is HTML 5 exclusive. Some users out there are still using HTML 4 browser compliance and below. so you'll need to place those inside the `<head></head>` which is usually best to do. Only in rare cases do you really need to use that, which I know all too well.

Comment: Not to tie up comments (or mean to be chatty), but you can also use an inline styling method which has been around for quite some time, so you'd be safe with that. But as I said earlier, there are rare cases where you're using this now as, is required (and really have no choice) and I worked on something once where for the life of me, was the only way to pull some trick off; long story but it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add each row to `$values` instead of replacing it each time.

Where you have:

```
$values=array(
      "title"=>$row['title'],
      "body"=>$row['body']
);
```

Change it to:

```
$values[] = array(
      "title"=>$row['title'],
      "body"=>$row['body']
);
```

And then where you have the display:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($values);$i++){
    echo $values["title"]."<br>";
    echo $values["body"]."<br>";
}
```

Change to:

```
foreach($values as $value){
    echo $value["title"]."<br>";
    echo $value["body"]."<br>";
}
```

Or using a FOR:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($values);$i++){
    echo $values[$i]["title"]."<br>";
    echo $values[$i]["body"]."<br>";
}
```

Comment: It worked thanks! i will accept answer in 8 minutes. but why do i have to do foreach loop?  $values[]=array("title"=>$row['title'],"body"=>$row['body']) returns whole row?

Comment: You dont HAVE to do a foreach, its just cleaner looking. Also a foreach ends on its own when it reaches the last array element. You can use a for loop and retrieve by index. I updated the answer with the for loop.

Comment: Also you could just do `$values[] = $row;` in your while loop method, since you are keeping the same keynames between them.

Answer (score 1):

you are reassigning $values to the last array you created each time, instead you should be adding the array you created to $values. use $values[] like below:

```
public function getContent(){
            $query="SELECT * FROM content";
            $result=$this->db->query($query);
            $values=array();
            if($result->num_rows>0){
                while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
                $values[]=array(
                    "title"=>$row['title'],
                    "body"=>$row['body']
                );
            }

        }
```